# Which topology is more optimized/recommended to work with?

Tags: unity, topology

I've got 2 images to share with you and get some tips on topology...

First one is much organic, however has more vertices,
Second has less verts but doesn't look organic,

What should I go for? The objects are going to be used in Unity

Thanks in advance.

[image: render0][image: render1]

Comment: Wth is going on here...? Is it an optical illusion or what? https://i.imgur.com/4x23BTX.png Can you show the objects with shading or upload a .blend file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten the 3rd one - these two objects are disconnected, and in this way - the lowest amount of polygons and no n-gons. This is more suitable for examples like this, then the addition to main surface is small.

In the second example not so many polygons are removed, because whey are going to be converted into triangles, so the front face has almost the same amount of polygons as in the first example. But basically the answer is it depends.

But I would prefer first example from this two, because:

- example like this is more suitable for animation
- may have fewer artifacts due to triangulation
- saving polygons is not so efficient as if you just make two boxes
- it is harder to work with n-gons (e.g. adding loop cuts), so second example is harder to maintain